# Biblatex: How to convert date field into year and month field?

Tags: biblatex

I have exported the bibliography from Zotero in biblatex format. All the references contain a date field, but now year field.

Is there a simple way (a tool, a script etc.) to convert the date field or to append year and month fields?

Example:

```
@article{kattan_timeseries_2015,
  title = {Time-series event-based prediction: An unsupervised learning framework based on genetic programming},  
  journaltitle = {Information Sciences},
  author = {Kattan, Ahmed and Fatima, Shaheen and Arif, Muhammad},
  date = {2015-04}
}
```

and I want to be

```
@article{kattan_timeseries_2015,
  title = {Time-series event-based prediction: An unsupervised learning framework based on genetic programming},  
  journaltitle = {Information Sciences},
  author = {Kattan, Ahmed and Fatima, Shaheen and Arif, Muhammad},
  date = {2015-04},
  year = {2015},
  month = {04}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You want a modification of an existing bib-file. From my point of view there is no relation to LaTeX/TeX but rather to perl

Comment: Why do you want it? Biblatex/biber can/will extract the year from the date.

Comment: `biblatex` can deal with the `date` field in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.  If you actually use `biblatex` in the end, this will only confuse everyone involved. And if you don't you shouldn't export in `biblatex` format in the first place, I think.

Comment: Interestingly, the contents of the `date` field always override the contents of the `year` and `month` field; the `day` field is not overwritten if it comes *after* the `date` field.

Comment: The bibliography style that I am using doesn't read the date field only the year field and the citation aren't display right. I can do a search replace all date field with year field, but there are cases when the date filed contains the year and month values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is something Biber can do in its tool mode.

Unfortunately, the solution originally suggested here ceased to work a while ago. Following https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/301 Biber was adjusted so things would work again. The fix will be available in Biber 2.15. For versions in between, I'm afraid I can not offer a simple Biber-based solution. (Maybe `bibtool` can help here.)

## Biber version 2.15 and above

We need the following config file, called, say, `biber-date.conf`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
  <datamodel>
    <fields>
      <field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">year</field>
      <field fieldtype="field" datatype="literal">month</field>
    </fields>
    <entryfields>
      <field>year</field>
      <field>month</field>
    </entryfields>
  </datamodel>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex">
      <map map_overwrite="1">
        <map_step map_field_source="date" map_match="[0-9]{4}-([0-9]{2})" map_final="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="montha" map_field_value="$1"/>
      </map>
      <map map_overwrite="1">
        <map_step map_field_source="date" map_match="([0-9]{4})" map_final="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="yeara" map_field_value="$1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

To convert the `date` fields in your `.bib` file run

```
biber --tool --configfile=biber-date.conf <yourbibfile>
```

For the example file `augustus.bib`

```
@article{kattan_timeseries_2015,
  title = {Time-series event-based prediction: An unsupervised learning framework based on genetic programming},  
  journaltitle = {Information Sciences},
  author = {Kattan, Ahmed and Fatima, Shaheen and Arif, Muhammad},
  date = {2015-04}
}
@book{lorem,
  title = {Lorem},  
  author = {Anne Uthor},
  date = {2015}
}
@book{ipsum,
  title = {Ipsum},  
  author = {Anne Uthor},
  date = {2015-08-07},
}
```

the output (which you can find in `augustus_bibertools.bib` after the `biber --tool --configfile=biber-date.conf augustus.bib` run) is

```
@article{kattan_timeseries_2015,
  author = {Kattan, Ahmed and Fatima, Shaheen and Arif, Muhammad},
  journaltitle = {Information Sciences},
  month = {4},
  title = {Time-series event-based prediction: An unsupervised learning framework based on genetic programming},
  year = {2015},
}

@book{lorem,
  author = {Uthor, Anne},
  title = {Lorem},
  year = {2015},
}

@book{ipsum,
  author = {Uthor, Anne},
  date = {2015-08-07},
  title = {Ipsum},
}
```

---

## Old versions of Biber

We need the following config file, called say `biber-date.conf`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map map_overwrite="1">
        <map_step map_field_source="date" map_match="[0-9]{4}?-([0-9]{2}?)" map_final="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="month" map_field_value="$1"/>
      </map>
      <map map_overwrite="1">
        <map_step map_field_source="date" map_match="([0-9]{4}?)" map_final="1"/>
        <map_step map_field_set="year" map_field_value="$1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

The regular expressions are not particularly elegant, but the first one copies the month position of the `date` field to the `month` field, the second maps the year position to the `year` field.

Now you just need to run `biber --tool --configfile=biber-date.conf <yourbibfile>`

On the example file `augustus.bib`

```
@article{kattan_timeseries_2015,
  title = {Time-series event-based prediction: An unsupervised learning framework based on genetic programming},  
  journaltitle = {Information Sciences},
  author = {Kattan, Ahmed and Fatima, Shaheen and Arif, Muhammad},
  date = {2015-04}
}
@book{lorem,
  title = {Lorem},  
  author = {Anne Uthor},
  date = {2015}
}
@book{ipsum,
  title = {Ipsum},  
  author = {Anne Uthor},
  date = {2015-08-07},
}
```

the output (which you can find in `augustus_bibertools.bib` after the `biber --tool --configfile=biber-date.conf augustus.bib` run) is

```
@article{kattan_timeseries_2015,
  author       = {Kattan, Ahmed and Fatima, Shaheen and Arif, Muhammad},
  date         = {2015-04},
  journaltitle = {Information Sciences},
  month        = {04},
  title        = {Time-series event-based prediction: An unsupervised learning framework based on genetic programming},
  year         = {2015},
}

@book{lorem,
  author = {Anne Uthor},
  date   = {2015},
  title  = {Lorem},
  year   = {2015},
}

@book{ipsum,
  author = {Anne Uthor},
  date   = {2015-08-07},
  month  = {08},
  title  = {Ipsum},
  year   = {2015},
}
```

Comment: If you also add `<output_resolve>1</output_resolve>` Biber will automatically resolve crossrefs/xrefs with inheritance, together with `<output_safechars>1</output_safechars>` you might come very close to creating a fully (BibTeX) downward-compatible version of your `.bib` file. (Though there is no such thing as "BibTeX compatible" as different styles support different fields.)

Comment: But please note the caveat mentioned in my comment to the question. A `year` and `month` field together with a `date` field will confuse Biber quite a bit, that is something one should avoid. Note that in the solution above possibly existing `month` and `years` are overwritten (the `map_overwrite="1"` does that).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your solution with biber 2.15. The only thing that changes in the bib-file is the order of fields.

Comment: @LukasCB Sorry, I don't have time to look into this in more detail at the moment. I suggest you open an issue at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues there were some changes in the data model handling of `--tool` mode and some more changes are lined up for Biber 2.16.

Comment: just did: https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/339

Answer (score 1):

The biber solution does not work anymore. This seems to be by design since the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf) (version 2.14) says

> Dates are normalised into DATE fields. Legacy YEAR fields are never output in BibTeX format data output.

I solve this using a regexp solution for the year (the month can be extracted similarly):

```
sed -e 's/\(.*\)date\(.*\)\([[:digit:]]\{4\}\).*\(\}.*\)/\1year\2\3\4/g' augustus.bib
```

Comment: if you have an electronic entry with an urldate field, that will get turned into urlyear with this :)

Answer (score 1):

After trying other solutions with no success, I ended up doing a Python script to process a list of files.
The pre-requisite is that date is alone in a line, and is writen in the canonical forma YYYY-MM-DD.
The program can process multipe files (FILES).

```
import os
import re

FILES = ["bibliografia.bib","standards.bib","bibdoslivrosesas.bib"]

TEMP = "temp.bib"

for arquivo in FILES:
    bak = arquivo+".bak"
    try:
        filew = open(TEMP,"w")
        with  open(arquivo,"r") as f:
            for linha in f:
                novalinha = linha.lstrip()
                if novalinha[:4] == "date" or novalinha[:4] == "DATE":
                    regexp = "\{[0-9\-]+\}"
                    m = re.search(regexp,novalinha).group(0)
                    # get year
                    print(m)
                    informacao = m.split("-")
                    if len(informacao) == 1:
                        filew.write("year = "+informacao[0]+",\n")
                    if len(informacao) == 2:
                        filew.write("year = "+informacao[0]+"},\n")
                        filew.write("month = {"+informacao[1]+",\n")
                    if len(informacao) == 3:
                        filew.write("year = "+informacao[0]+"},\n")
                        filew.write("month = {"+informacao[1]+"},\n")
                        filew.write("day = {"+informacao[2]+",\n")
                else:
                    filew.write(linha)
    finally:
        filew.close()
    os.rename(arquivo,bak)
    os.rename(TEMP,arquivo)
```

Answer (score 1):

To anyone coming here and with Biber 2.15/2.16 and struggles to use the fixes provided here:

Try the solutions provided in https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/322 :

- `--output-field-replace=date:year` https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/322#issuecomment-657228997
- `--output-legacy-dates` https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/322#issuecomment-658273552

Both worked in my case, which is better depends whether you're using month/day as well -- see discussion in the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another version, that makes sure that something like urldate does not get turned into urlyear (which happens with @Sebastians answer), and that does not replace date with year, but creates two new fields, one for year, one for month.

**long story short:**

```
sed -r 's/([ \t]+)(date)([ \t={]+)([[:digit:]]{4})([^0-9]{1})([[:digit:]]{2})(.*)/\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\n \1year\3\4\7\n \month\3\6\7/g' inputfile.bib | bibtool  -o outputfile.bib
```

Explanation:

0. for this to work, there can't be a date with day included in the date-field. I don't have any in my own library, and have never seen it, but to check use ripgrep or grep to verify that there isn't one:

   rg -P '[ \t]date.*\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}' work-bibliotek.bib
1. instead of

(.*)

in the beginning of the regex that captures all, i use

```
([ \t]+)
```

so that a field like urldate does that get replaced with urlyear. this version does require that there is actually a space before the field-name 'date' .

This can be easily secured by running bibtool on the bibfile before prior to the sed command:

```
  bibtool -i input.bib -o output.bib
```

2. don't replace the field, but make two new ones, that include year and month.
3. use sed -r where you don't have to use escape characters all the time, it's confusing

I pipe it to bibtool and output from there to align the month field with the others