# How to switch from biblatex+biber to natbib+bibtex?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, natbib, biber

### Context

I use the `biblatex` package coupled with `biber` (see [terminology disambiguation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25702)) for my personal writings.

I want to submit a paper using a template requiring the `natbib` package — hence the use of `bibtex`. However, I use `biber` features in my `.bib` file (such as crossref) that are not handled  by `natbib`, making the switch not straightforward.

### Question

Given the`.bib` file where all my references are stored, which are all the steps/modifications needed to switch from {`biblatex`+`biber`} to {`natbib`+`bibtex`}?

Comment: Partial answer addressing the `biber` -> `bibtex` compatibility: [Converting from biblatex to BibTeX format using biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114787/converting-from-biblatex-to-bibtex-format-using-biber)

Comment: It also depends on the `.bst` style you use with `natbib`, some styles support an URL field, some don't. So it can get arbitrarily messy.

Comment: Is `authoryear` answering your question? (The class I have to use includes this line: `\RequirePackage[authoryear]{natbib}`). Within the `tex` document, the bibliography is called as following: `\begin{thebibliography}{9}`.

Comment: Also related: [Compatibility of bibtex and biblatex bibliography files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37095/compatibility-of-bibtex-and-biblatex-bibliography-files?rq=1)

Comment: Biber can do lots of the dirty work, it can for example convert the `date` field that `.bst` styles probably wont understand to `year` and `month`. [Biblatex: How to convert date field into year and month field?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/265895/35864). I can also imagine Biber putting the `url` and `urldate` field together in the `note` field if that be necessary.

Comment: You seem to have collected quite some info yourself. What would you like an answer to add to that? Do you maybe want to write an answer yourself?

Comment: I am still looking a 'for dummies' (i.e. step by step) method starting with "I have my `.bib` file, what do I do now ?". I'll try to write an answer, but need to understand linked threads first (-;

Comment: Have you already chosen a bibliography style? If so, which one? Please also tell us if there are entry types and field names in your bib file that are recognized by biblatex/biber (e.g., `date`) but not by BibTeX.

Comment: `natbib` is load with the `authoryear` option. Is it an answer to your question? (The LaTeX template of the journal is to find [here](http://www.designsciencejournal.org/authors/)) Regarding incompatible fields/types, I use `inbook`, `urldate`, `crossref`, some alias (e.g. `phdthesis`) etc. but no exotic custom `x-data` types.

Answer (score 3):

> **Disclaimer:** This answer is a work-in-progress, since final solution have not been found yet.

Roadmap overview

1. Clean-up the `biber`-specific features of your `.bib` file using `biber-tool`
2. ...

---

## 1/ Clean-up the `biber`-specific features of your `.bib` file using `biber-tool`

The `.bib` file might use `biber`-specific features (such as the `@inbook` entry, `crossref` or `urldate` fields, etc.). A new `.bib` file that is `BibTeX`-compatible must thus be generated. Following answer based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265895/biblatex-how-to-convert-date-field-into-year-and-month-field) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114787/converting-from-biblatex-to-bibtex-format-using-biber) treads.

- Create a file named `myBiberConfig.conf` containing following code. It defines how your original `.bib` file should be transformed in order to be `BibTeX`-compatible.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
    <output_resolve>1</output_resolve>
    <output_safechars>1</output_safechars>
    <sourcemap>
        <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
            <map map_overwrite="1">
                <map_step map_field_source="date" map_match="[0-9]{4}?-([0-9]{2}?)" map_final="1"/>
                <map_step map_field_set="month" map_field_value="$1"/>
            </map>
            <map map_overwrite="1">
                <map_step map_field_source="date" map_match="([0-9]{4}?)" map_final="1"/>
                <map_step map_field_set="year" map_field_value="$1"/>
            </map>
        </maps>
        <maps datatype="bibtex">
            <map>
                <map_step map_type_source="conference" map_type_target="inproceedings"/>
                <map_step map_type_source="electronic" map_type_target="online"/>
                <map_step map_type_source="www" map_type_target="online"/>
            </map>
            <map>
                <map_step map_type_source="mastersthesis" map_type_target="thesis" map_final="1"/>
                <map_step map_field_set="type" map_field_value="mathesis"/>
            </map>
            <map>
                <map_step map_type_source="phdthesis" map_type_target="thesis" map_final="1"/>
                <map_step map_field_set="type" map_field_value="phdthesis"/>
            </map>
            <map>
                <map_step map_type_source="techreport" map_type_target="report" map_final="1"/>
                <map_step map_field_set="type" map_field_value="techreport"/>
            </map>
            <map>
                <map_step map_field_source="address" map_field_target="location"/>
                <map_step map_field_source="school" map_field_target="institution"/>
                <map_step map_field_source="annote" map_field_target="annotation"/>
                <map_step map_field_source="archiveprefix" map_field_target="eprinttype"/>
                <map_step map_field_source="journal" map_field_target="journaltitle"/>
                <map_step map_field_source="primaryclass" map_field_target="eprintclass"/>
                <map_step map_field_source="key" map_field_target="sortkey"/>
                <map_step map_field_source="pdf" map_field_target="file"/>
            </map>
        </maps>
    </sourcemap>
</config>
```

- Process your original `.bib` file with the `--tool` option of `biber`

  ```
  biber --tool --configfile=myBiberConfig.conf <yourbibfile>.bib
  ```
- Your processed `.bib` file is the freshly created `<yourbibfile>_bibertool.bib`

Comment: Note that one problem with this project is that there is no such thing as *BibTeX (or even `natbib`) compatibility*. The fields and entry types that you can use are ultimately decided on by your `.bst` file, some support a `url` field, some don't etc. There are some features of `biblatex` that no `.bst` style can deal with (as far as I know), the `date` field being one, advanced crossref being another.

Comment: Actually, what I want is only to be able to use my `.bib` database (that is intended for a processing using `biber`) with the given template (that require `natbib` package, hence a processing with `bibtex`. If every feature of `biber` (e.g. `url`) are not available, I don't care as long as it is not needed by journal's `.bst` style.

Comment: What I'm saying is that an answer can depend quite heavily on the exact style you use. A problem with unsupported `url` or `date` field is that if they are not "recovered" in some way for the `.bst` to be able to understand them the important information contained there is lost.

Comment: Got it! The mapping (via the `xml` code) is thus "style (i.e. `.bst`) dependent", right ? As no specific information is given in the template, I'll assume the `authoryear` style is used.

Comment: Mhhh, no the necessary mapping will in last detail depend on the `.bst` you plan to use with BibTeX. It does not depend on the `biblatex` style used. (`authoryear` is not a `.bst` style that I would know)

Answer (score 0):

To add to the existing answers. For `bibtex-2.16` a minimal configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Got the date from https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mkouhia/f00fea7fc8d4effd9dfd/raw/500e9dbc6aa43a47e39c45ba230738ff4544709f/biblatex-to-bibtex.conf -->
<config>
  <output_fieldcase>lower</output_fieldcase>
  <output_resolve>1</output_resolve>
  <output_safechars>1</output_safechars>
  <output_format>bibtex</output_format>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex">
      <!-- Easy type conversions -->
      <map>
        <map_step map_type_source="report" map_type_target="techreport"/>
        <map_step map_type_source="online" map_type_target="misc"/>
      </map>
      <!-- Date to year, month -->
      <map>
        <map_step map_field_source="date"
        map_field_target="year" />
      </map>
      <map>
        <map_step map_field_source="year"
        map_match="(\d{4}|\d{2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})"
        map_final="1" />
        <map_step map_field_source="year"
        map_match="(\d{4}|\d{2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})"
        map_replace="$1" />
        <map_step map_field_set="month" map_origfieldval="1" />
        <map_step map_field_source="month"
        map_match="(\d{4}|\d{2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})"
        map_replace="$2" />
      </map>
      <map>
        <map_step map_field_source="year"
        map_match="(\d{4}|\d{2})-(\d{1,2})" map_final="1" />
        <map_step map_field_source="year"
        map_match="(\d{4}|\d{2})-(\d{1,2})" map_replace="$1" />
        <map_step map_field_set="month" map_origfieldval="1" />
        <map_step map_field_source="month"
        map_match="(\d{4}|\d{2})-(\d{1,2})" map_replace="$2" />
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

Coupled with a few command line options:

```bash
biber --tool --configfile=biberConf.xml references.bib --output-file refsTmp.bib --output-legacy-date --output-field-replace=location:address,journaltitle:journal
```

Is sufficient. More [details are here](https://rgoswami.me/posts/zotero-biblatex-bibtex/). Note that sufficiency in this case is defined as being recognized as valid `bibtex` by `sphinx`, and this should not be used without more work for other cases (like journal templates).